# AngularFire2 Firebase promise doesnt work under mac

Tags: node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I have in my pacakge.json following version of firebase

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc0",
"firebase": "^4.3.1"
```

in my Ubuntu when I build for Android it works flawlessly without any problem. But when I try to build in Mac for Android or IOS it gives error

```
 signInWithGoogle(res): firebase.Promise<any> {
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
}
```

Here is the error

> typescript: 
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts, line: 11
>
> c Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.

Comment: You need to give more code so we can reproduce that. How are you "building" it?

Comment: ionic cordova build ios

Comment: ionic cordova run android
ionic cordova run ios


using these commands in Ubuntu and Mac. But in mac it fails as if the angularfire2 version in the node_modules is different than in Ubuntu although having the same version number.

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded the firebase and it is working fine now.

```
"firebase": "^3.9.*"
```